# Select distinct with many columns

Tags: distinct

I've made a simple earch engine in ASP divided in more steps; every step asks progressive question and, in the end, I've got a list of items. The final select interests a view linking two tables with all the data needed to satisfy the final query. As result, I've got many duplicates, and I want to use Distinct, but with no result, I still got duplicate items. The query is

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id_prodotto, titolo, trinciatura_arbusti, taglio_erba, bioenergia, frutteti_vigneti, superfici_pendenza, residui_colturali, terreni_bagnati, terreni_sabbiosi, terreni_salicei, terreni_sassosi, telaio_fisso, telaio_spostatile, telaio_reversibile, potenza_min, potenza_max, larghezza_lavoro_cm, ordine, categoria, img1, nome, terreni_normali  FROM vista_ricerca WHERE "&QueryAdd&" ORDER BY ordine ASC"
```

where QueryAdd is the final query, obtained adding up the query of the various steps.

Comment: Can you give an example of `QueryAdd`?

Comment: Sure thing. A complete, 4 steps QueryAdd can be something like

[code](categoria = 'fresatrici' OR categoria = 'vangatrici' or categoria = 'trinciatutto') AND terreni_bagnati = 'True' AND terreni_sabbiosi = 'True' AND telaio_fisso = 'True' AND CONVERT(int, larghezza_lavoro_cm) > 2250 [/code]

Comment: OK, your problem is due to you doing a dinstinct on an entire DB row, and id_prodotto is different for each row.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case, it's a view that links two tables, and there are many rows with the same id_prodotto. If i simply interrogate "SELECT DISTINCT id_prodotto FROM vista_ricerca WHERE "&QueryAdd&" ORDER BY ordine ASC"", the system gives me an error, since I need all the other data to satisfy QueryAdd.